# Are rational varieties simply connected?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Is it true that every smooth rational variety X is simply connected? How is the proof?
Would it be still true if X has mild (for example orbifold) singularities?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes! (I assume it was implicit in your question that the variety be *projective*?)

More generally: any smooth, complex, rationally connected projective variety is simply connected. See Debarre's book ("Higher dimensional algebraic geometry").

Alternatively, take a look at Debarre's Bourbaki talk ("Varietes rationnellement connexes"). The idea is that a rationally connected variety has no holomorphic forms, so by Hodge theory the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ is acyclic, implying $\chi(X,\mathcal{O}_X) = 1$. If $f : Y \to X$ is a connected etale cover, then $Y$ is again rationally connected, so by the same argument $\chi(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y) = 1$, so $\deg{f} = 1$. So $X$ is simply connected.

In positive characteristic the Hodge theory fails, so the argument as such doesn't stand, but you may still get the simple connectedness as a consequence of the fibration theorem of Graber-Harris-Starr-de Jong. See the mentioned Bourbaki expose.

Comment: Do I understand right that your paragraph beginning "Alternatively" shows that over the complex numbers the algebraic fundamental group is trivial, but leaves open the possibility that the classical fundamental group is non-trivial and without finite-index subgroups? Is the classical fundamental group of a rationally connected, smooth, complex projective variety known by other means to be trivial? 

Comment: Yes indeed; the full proof of the *classical* simple connectedness of a complex rationally connected smooth projective variety can be found in Chapter 4 of Debarre's book.

Comment: By the way, the nodal curve ${y^2 = x^3}$ is not simply connected, so the result does not extend to singular rationally connected varieties.

Comment: @Tim.  The topological fundamental group of any rationally chain connected projective variety is a priori finite by Chow variety / Hilbert scheme methods: a degree of a certain Chow variety of curves gives an upper bound on the size of the fundamental group.  Combined with the arguments in Debarre's article (which are originally due to Koll\'ar), this implies simple connectedness of the fundamental group of a smooth, projective rationally connected variety.

Comment: @Vesselin: The curve $y^2-x^3$ is cuspidal, not nodal, although your point is correct.  In my comment, the variety should be unibranch.

Comment: Indeed, I intended to write $y^2 = x^3 + x^2$ (for a nodal rational curve). Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Tim: My question was about the classical fundamental group. What is the definition algebraic one?
@Vesselin: I still believe we can say some thing if the singularities are terminal or something nice.

Comment: Mohammad: being algebraically simply connected means that there are no non-trivial connected etale covers. Such covers are finite, while in topology one makes no finiteness condition on the covers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Étale_fundamental_group


Comment: @TimPerutz but do you know an example of a connected smooth projective complex variety that is etale simply connected but is not classically simply connected? I have heard that is an open problem.

Comment: Excuse me. Hodge theory says that $H^m(X, \mathcal O_X) = \bigoplus_{p+q=m} H^q(X, \Omega_X^p)$. In Debarre's book, he shows that $H^0(X, (\Omega_X^p)^{\otimes k}) = 0$, why does this condition imply that $H^q(X, \Omega_X^p) = 0$.

Answer (score 15):

Every proper, normal, rational variety over an algebraically closed field is simply connected. Dmitri explains this via the smooth case and resolution of singularities, but this is true in any characteristic: see SGA 1, XI, Cor. 1.2.

EDIT: As Dmitri and Vesselin observe, the "proof" in SGA1 is sketchy, to say the least. One can argue as follows: if $X$ is our variety, there is a birational morphism $U\to X$ where $U=\mathbb{P}^n\smallsetminus Z$ and $Z$ has codimension $\geq2$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$. By the purity theorem, $U$ is simply connected. So any étale covering of $X$ is generically trivial (because its pullback on $U$ is trivial), hence trivial since $X$ is normal.

In fact, this proves that if $X$ and $Y$ (both proper and  normal) are birationally equivalent, and $Y$ is regular and simply connected, then $X$ is simply connected. But this does not answer Vesselin's final question.

Comment: Dear Laurent I decided to check the reference and it looks to me that the proof of the fact is not really there. It is proven in two ways that projective spaces over algebraically closed fields are simply connected SGA 1. XI. Prop. 1.1, ( arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206203v2.pdf) and then comes corollary 1.2 without an actual proof. It is just said there that the proof is the same as for projective space :). Could you indicate how to make this an actual proof? I am asking this because I want to see how to make a proof over C without Hironaka's resolution of singularities.

Comment: I had the same point as Dmitri. In expose X it is shown, as an application of the Zariski-Nagata purity theorem, that the algebraic fundamental group of a complete *regular* variety is birationally invariant. In particular, this certainly contains a proof of the simple connectedness of regular proper rational varieties over an alg. closed field. Statement XI, Cor. 1.2 simply refers to this birational invariance. Does the birational invariance extend to normal varieties?

Comment: @Vesselin: Is the affine line birational to the punctured line?
If yes, whatever the characteristic, then you have two birational smooth curves over an alg. closed field whose fundamental groups are distinct. 

Comment: The fundamental group is certainly not a birational invariant for normal proper varieties. For example, consider a cone over a curve of genus $>0$ (and its desingularisation).

Comment: @ulrich: Thanks for the example!
@ACL: I had in mind *proper* varieties.

Answer (score 14):

In positive characteristic, the (étale) fundamental group of a rationally connected variety is finite (Kollár, Inventiones Math., 1993, [EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/144127)).

And this happens: Let us assume that the base field has characteristic $p$,
where $p\neq 5$ and $p\not\equiv 1\pmod 5$. Then, the hypersurface
with equation $X_0^5+\dots+X_3^5=0$ in $\mathbf P^3$ is unirational;
so is its quotient by the obvious action of $\mu_5$ (a surface of general type
known as the Godeaux surface), which
is therefore an unirational variety with fundamental group $\mathbf Z/5$.

However, Ekedahl has proved that this group is prime to the characteristic.
I discussed that in my Bourbaki Seminar talk, «Points rationnels et groupes fondamentaux, applications de la cohomologie $p$-adique», *Astérisque* **294**, p. 125-146, [Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_2002-2003__45__125_0/), arXiv:[math/0303052](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303052).

Comment: Also using Raynaud's work on the Abhyankar conjecture combined with Koll\'ar's method, in characteristic $p$, any $p$-group acting on a smooth, projective, separably rationally connected variety has a fixed point.  This is stronger than the $p$-part of the fundamental group being trivial, since that only implies there is a point with nontrivial stabilizer, not that there is a fixed point (i.e., point whose stabilizer is the entire group).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks! But may I ask for details?

Comment: @ACL: I am not an expert on Abhyankar's conjecture, but I believe that Raynaud proved that for every algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p$, and for every "quasi-p-group" $G$, there exists a finite, flat morphism of smooth, pointed curves over $k$, $f:(C,q)\to (B,p)$ that is a $G$-torsor over `$B\setminus\{p\}$` and that is totally ramified over $p$, i.e., the inverse image of `$\{p\}$` equals `$\{q\}$`.  Given an action of $G$ on a smooth, projective, separably rationally connected variety $X$, form the diagonal action of $G$ on $C\times X$.  contd.

Comment: contd. Denote the quotient of this $G$-action by $C\times X \to Y$.  The morphism $f\circ \text{pr}_C:C\times X \to B$ is $G$-invariant, hence factors through a morphism $\pi:Y\to B$.  This is a morphism that satisfies the hypotheses of the "rationally connected fibration theorem".  Thus there exists a section.  The inverse image of this section in $C\times X$ is the image of a $G$-equivariant section of $\text{pr}_C$, i.e., the graph of a $G$-equivariant morphism $s:C\to X$.  In particular, the image of $q$ is a $G$-fixed point.  This is "Koll\'ar's method". Ekedahl's method might work too...

Comment: I believe that the Godeaux surface is a quotient of your quintic surface, not the quintic itself.

Answer (score 9):

I decided to rewrite the answer so it is more clear.

Smooth complex rational projective varieties are indeed simply-connected as is explained in the first answer to the question. My point is that from this fact it follows immediately that normal complex rational projective varieties are always simply-connected. Here is a proof.

**Proof.** Let $X$ be an normal complex projective variety and $X'\to X$ be a resolution of singularities. Then we have a homomorphism $\pi_1(X')\to \pi_1(X)$. I claim that is is surjective. In order to see this one just needs to know that every loop on $X$ can be lifted to $X'$ and this is true since all the fibres of $X'\to X$ are connected since $X$ is normal.

So if $X$ is rational then $X'$ is smooth rational and $\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(X')=0$

Comment: Aren't you missing the words "rationally connected" in a couple of places? I know a few smooth complex projective varieties that are indeed not simply-connected... 

Comment: Sandor, thank you :), I completely agree with you, I added missing words. In fact I was meaning "rational complex projective varieties". I don't know what is the definition of rationally connected projective varieties in the case they are singular. For example, if you consider a cone over a genus $g>0$ curve, every to points can be connected by a two $\mathbb P^1$'s (through the center of the cone), but I don't think this variety should be called rationally connected...

Comment: A normal projective variety $X$ is (separably) rationally connected if there exists a finite-type integral scheme $T$ and a morphism $F : T \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to X$ such that the obvious morphism $T \times \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to X \times X$ is dominant (and generically smooth). 

Comment: Thank you Vesselin. The property of been rationally connected is a birational invariant, I guess?

Comment: Yes! So, in char. 0, $X$ is rationally connected iff. it has a smooth projective rationally connected (birational) model. But since resolution of singularities is not available in positive characteristic, this definition is the general one. In general, in any characteristic, a smooth *separably* rationally connected variety is simply connected. (And as noted above, all we can say about non-separably rationally connected varieties in char. $p > 0$ is that their fundamental group is finite of order prime to $p$).

Answer (score 3):

In characteristic zero you do not neen rational. It is enough rationally connected.

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective, rationally connected variety over a field of characteristic zero. Then

- Any finite étale cover of $X$ is trivial;
- $X$ is simply connected.

You can find this, for instance, in O. Debarre "*Higher-Dimensional Algebraic Geometry*", Corollary 4.18.